# How convert rows products to columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rows

I have 3 Tables SQL

- products[id, name_product]
- customers [id, name_customer]
- data_prodcuts[id, id_product, id_customer, quantity_data]

How convert in PHP & MYSQL rows table prodcuts name to columns 
 and get group id_product sum(quantity_data) for all customers rows.

Thanks ..

I'm use SQL

```
SELECT 
data_prodcuts.id_product, 
sum(data_prodcuts.quantity_data) as total,
data_prodcuts.id_customer,
products.name_product,
customers.name_customer
FROM data_prodcuts
LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = data_prodcuts.id_product
LEFT JOIN customers ON customers.id = data_prodcuts.id_customer
GROUP BY name_product, name_customer
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? The answer wont fit both.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: I'm use PHP & MySQL

Comment: search on pivot this question is asked alot..

Comment: This transformation is called pivoting and has been asked and answered many times here on SO. The linked duplicate topics describe you how to create pivot tables within MySQL. The `MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns` also describes how to do the pivoting for unknown number of products.

Comment: The End 

SQL : 

SELECT 
    id_customer, 
    sum( if( id_product = 1, quantity_data, 0 ) ) AS P1,  
    sum( if( id_product = 2, quantity_data, 0 ) ) AS P2
FROM 
    data_products 
GROUP BY 
    id_customer;

Comment: Please don't post the answer in the question. Since your question is a duplicate, your answer probably applies to at least one of the duplicate targets, so post your answer there (as an answer). If you don't think your question is a duplicate, please [edit] to explain why (if that's what you want to do, I suggest you read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194479/349538) before doing anything).